# Maximum Mean Discrepancy (implementation with Python and Scikitlearn) and Uncertanties

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, probability-distribution

I am using this [code](https://github.com/jindongwang/transferlearning/blob/master/code/distance/mmd_numpy_sklearn.py) from [Jindong Wang](https://github.com/jindongwang) to estimate MMD (Maximum Mean Discrepancy) with the aim of distinguishing between different characteristics of time series that I artificially generate following this skcikit-learn [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_compare_gpr_krr.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-compare-gpr-krr-py). I started with simple A*sin(wx+phi) to test if it is possible to differentiate phases, amplitudes or frequencies using such an approach by comparing each data set with the primary sen(x). The idea is that distances must be increasing as I chose larger frequencies or amplitudes. I have two questions.

1. How can I estimate an uncertainty related to the MMD distances? (this is a more theoretical question)
2. How can I optimize (in terms of memory and my arrays) to be able to use long time series with more than 10000-time points with x-y elements?
3. Why it works fine for differences in amplitudes but not for phases or frequencies? Could it be related to the sampling frequency of the data?

Comment: While time series mentioned, is it correct that time dimension used here just as first axis with no priority over target values? If so, then question is about MMD between 2-dimensional distributions (yes, with peculiarity -- stretched along X-axis but still just 2d)

Comment: I found very useful material from Arthur Gretton to help me. I how it could help others. http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~gretton/coursefiles/rkhscourse.html and https://github.com/karlnapf/ds3_kernel_testing/blob/master/solutions.ipynb